# UML: Return type as collection in class diagram

Tags: uml

let's say that the method `getRandomObjects` in the class `Builder` returns a collection with randomly generated objects of the class/type `RandomObject`. The method uses a local variable of a collection type, so the objects are not stored permanently in the class `Builder`.

What would be the correct relation between these classes in a UML class diagram? I think the class `Builder` depends on the class `RandomObject` but I am not really sure ... it could be also like a temporary association?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply indicate the return value to be an array by using square brackets like this:

[image]

It would also be possible to use a generic collection class with `RandomObject`s. But that's probably over-engineered.